# Why is the height of superscripts different in tikzpicture compared to maths environments?

Tags: tikz-pgf, superscripts

Consider this minimal example:

[image]

Why is the height of the superscript slightly lower in the `tikzpicture` and how can I get it to look like it does in the `equation` (or in this case `flalign*`) environment?

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength\parindent{0cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
F_i^x &&
\end{flalign*}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {$F_i^x$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the first is typeset in display style and the second is in inline style maths. To get the same formatting in the Ti*k*Z picture as in the `flalign*` environment (or any other displayed maths environment), you can use `\displaystyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength\parindent{0cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
F_i^x &&
\end{flalign*}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {$\displaystyle F_i^x$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! Is there a way to activate `\displaystyle` for all `$...$` text within a `tikzpicture`?

Comment: @Milo I think you could do `\usepackage{etoolbox}\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\everymath{\displaystyle}}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I recommend `\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\displaystyle}` if doing something at all, else you erase whatever `\everymath` may contain.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I am biased because my package `mathastext` uses `\everymath/\everydisplay` for some tasks `:)`